# Convert lead into a contact using a logic hook

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I looked in the dev guide and online but can't seem to find any code examples. I'm just trying to convert a lead into a contact.

For example I have a lead with ID: 7, what I'm trying to do is possibly modify a bean property to convert that lead into a contact (not sure if this approach is correct). Something like

> $bean->convert("Contact");
>
> $bean->save();

Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sugar/suite, conversion is a process which is copying a bean from one module to another module e.g. lead into contact.

I have been using this function to make it happen.

```
function outright_copy_bean($old_bean){
    $new_bean = new $old_bean->object_name;
            foreach($new_bean->field_defs as $key => $value){
                if(in_array($key, array("id", "date_entered"))){
                    continue;
                }
                if($value["type"] == "link"){
                    continue;
                }
                $new_bean->$key = $old_bean->$key;
            }
    $new_id = $new_bean->save();
    return $new_id
 }
```

Comment: thank you, where do you call the bean factory to specify what type of bean the new bean will be?

Comment: This can be called at after_save logic hook of lead.